# What are recommended JAX-RS combinations?

Tags: java, rest, enterprise

I've been using JSF with PrimeFaces and Seam for quite some time now, and while I admire the work the PF team has put in there, I don't think I'm going to implement my next project with such a heavyweight combination.

Instead, I am looking for a JQuery-UI based, decoupled user interface and an XML-based, RESTful web service model. JAX-RS seems to be the ticket on this one, but I'm not sure which implementation/combination to pick.

Here's what I'm looking for:

- Decoupled model for JQuery-UI view/viewmodel
- Simple mapping from URL to Java model operation
- Easy session and scope management (e.g. @SessionScoped, @ApplicationScoped, ...)
- Ability to integrate EE features (e.g. @PersistenceContext)

Has anyone a set of good container/framework suggestions for this scenario? What options in terms of servers, containers, REST implementations do I have here?

Thanks for your input here and kind regards

Pascal

Comment: Everything but your first point is part of Java EE 6/7.

Comment: So, if I set up a Glassfish server I'm good to go? I can use JAX-RS from scratch?

Comment: Yes, JAX-RS is part of Java EE 6 and Glassfish is the Reference Implementation of a Java EE 6 container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Tichodroma pointed out, what I was actually looking for is a lightweight Java EE 6 container featuring JAX-RS, ideally a Java EE 6 Web Profile implementation with JAX-RS. Luckily, TomEE JAXRS seems to be exactly what I was looking for:

http://tomee.apache.org/comparison.html